# how to disable automatic UV generation?

Tags: uv, properties, dynamic-topology

This dyntopo popup really gets into my nerves. Everytime I create a primitive form, Blender creates automatically an UV map. Is there some way to disable the auto generation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure thing ! Just after adding your primitive, type <kbd>F9</kbd> or open the foldout in the bottom left of your screen.
[image]

It will remember the setting for this kind of primitive in the file so next time you add a cube for example the box will be unchecked.